# How to check for reversed order string tuple and eliminate them from the file in python?

Tags: python

I want to remove reversed order string tuples from my large text file (>16M lines).

For example, if I have the following two lines in my file:

```
352_0F, 352_1F,  0.913
352_1F, 352_0F,  0.913
```

The expected output would be keep either of those lines (instead of both) as:

```
352_0F, 352_1F,  0.913
```

FYI: The third column `col3` will be same for a tuple and its reversed order tuple.

I tried the following code, but it is not working as expected.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)

with open("OUTPUT.txt","w") as output:
    for fileName in ["Large_INPUT.txt"]:
        with open(fileName,'r') as file1:
            for line in file1:
                col1,col2,value = line.split(",")
                if (col1,col2) not in data:
                     if (col2,col1) not in data:
                         data[(col1,col2,value)]
                         output.write(f"{col1},{col2} {value}\n")
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: When you say "it is not working as expected" please state what the code does and what you expected it to do.

Comment: how much memory do you have? Can you hold the whole file in memory? If so, this looks like `lines = {(frozenset(col1, col2), col3) for col1, col2, col3 in f.readlines().split(',')}`

Comment: Presumably your input lines from `data` are strings. But your test `if (col1,col2) not in data:` is literally testing if the tuple `("352_0F"," 352_1F")` is in your data - not the string `"352_0F, 352_1F"`. Those are different things. So, either read in `data` as string and test for the (possibly reversed) string in `data`, or read in `data` as another data structure, say tuple of string sorted alphanumerically. Your choice. Also, be careful that string testing does not match against col3. Either way, this is pretty easy, please try your own code and post it here when you get stuck.

Comment: Tip: just play around with the code manually, interactively until you get the test right on one single line of input.

Comment: What are you trying to do with line `data[(col1,col2)]`?

Comment: Also, consider making small file, e.g. of 10 lines, and debugging your program on it

Comment: Hi all, the question is updated to include the full code I tried. But that is not giving me the expected output. Can anybody give me some edits to this or suggest other possible methods? I'm quite new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code has a list of a single file, I am assuming you are generalizing it to work with multiple files. In that case you failed to mention something, do you want the combinations to persist across files? You are close with your implementation. Instead of using a dictionary to get O(1) searches you can use the simpler structure, set, and also get O(1) searching.

## persistent over list of files

```
found_combinations = set()
with open("OUTPUT.txt", "w") as output:
    for fileName in ["Large_INPUT.txt"]:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as file1:
            for line in file1:
                cols = [col.strip() for col in line.strip().split(',')]
                new_combination = frozenset(cols)
                if new_combination not in found_combinations:
                    found_combinations.add(new_combination)
                    out = ', '.join(cols) + '\n'
                    output.write(out)
```

## not persistent over files

```
with open("OUTPUT.txt", "w") as output:
    for fileName in ["Large_INPUT.txt"]:
        found_combinations = set()
        with open(fileName, 'r') as file1:
            for line in file1:
                cols = [col.strip() for col in line.strip().split(',')]
                new_combination = frozenset(cols)
                if new_combination not in found_combinations:
                    found_combinations.add(new_combination)
                    out = ', '.join(cols) + '\n'
                    output.write(out)
```

Note that the only difference between the two versions is the placement of `found_combinations = set()`

Comment: This is working fine. But the only issue is that the output lines does not preserve the same format as input. For example, the line 352_0F, 352_1F,  0.913 is outputted as 352_0F,  0.913, 352_1F. Which part of this code should I corrected?

Comment: Modified answer to reflect comment.